# Weird line effect in a Floyd-Steinberg Dithering print image (DNP DS620)

Tags: c#, printing, dithering

Hello I have an image which I apply a Floyd-Steinberg Dithering effect to (C# app).

When I save this image there is no problem with the image and the result is pretty good, but when I print it there is weird line one the image (darker line of ~10 pixel every ~10 pixel)

I don't know if its a compression problem or a printer problem.

Anyone already have this problem ?

Comment: Please provide an example image and some code of how you implemented your code.